# Looking to string match across strings in an array

Tags: sql, presto

Example of input:

```
id  col  
1   ["{test: a_b}", "{test: c_d}"]
2   ["{test: c_d}", "{test: e_f}"]
3   ["{test: e_f}", "{test: g_h}"]
```

I would like to filter out rows that have either `a` OR `d` within their test variable:

```
id  col  
1   ["{test: a_b}", "{test: c_d}"]
2   ["{test: c_d}", "{test: e_f}"]
```

I've gotten this far:

```
any_match(col, x -> json_extract_scalar(x, '$.test') IN (['a','b']))
```

This gets me close but its not a string match this is looking for exact matches. I'm wondering how to add the string match to my code above.

Comment: Would you prefer using `sql` query? You can use `WHERE col LIKE "%a%" OR col LIKE "%d%"`

Answer (score 0):

Using SQL query would solve the problem.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col LIKE "%a%" OR col LIKE "%d%";
```